# how to format long string to add a space after each number

Tags: java

I have this long string
"Ab1ac2axd3nxn70-00-0-0"
For the life of me I cannot figure out how to separate that string in java to look like this.
"Ab1 ac2 axd3 nxn7 0-0 0-0-0"
I am thinking I need to use delimiters but I don't know the code for the desired format I want and also don't know how to correctly write it.

It might help to know that zeros will only occur as the form "0-0" or "0-0-0" if it is attached to letters it will only be like this ab30-0 now I don't want to put spaces between the dashes and the zeros but if this occurs"0-00-0-0" I want it to be formatted like this "0-0 0-0-0"

Comment: First decide what you really  want to do.  Your title says one thing---add a space after each letter--but your example says another---insert a space after each sequence consisting of some letters followed by a single digit.

Comment: Sorry I meant number in the title

Comment: There is no space after each `0`.

Comment: You're right, but I want to be able to format it so that if two zeros occur in a row with now dash between them, add a space. Like in my example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.  There may be a more elegant solution, but this definitely works:

```
public class Delimiter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Ab1ac2axd3nxn70-00-0-0";
    int l = input.length() - 1;
    char[] inputChars = input.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      char c = inputChars[i];
      output.append(c);

      if (Character.isDigit(c) && inputChars[i+1] != '-')
        output.append(' ');
    }

    output.append(inputChars[l]);
    System.out.println(output.toString());
  }
}
```